# The running time of the algorithm

Tags: java

I did not figure out why the running time the Algorithm below is O(nlogn). Could anyone help me out?

```
public static boolean unique2(int[] data) {
  int n= data.length;
  int[] temp= Arrays.copyOf(data,n);
  Arrays.sort(temp);
  for (int j=0; j<n-1;j++)
    if (temp[j]==temp[j+1])
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You did not write anything that is O(nlogn) but the `Arrays.sort(temp);` probably is.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.sort(temp)` takes `O(nlogn)`, since that's the running time of the most efficient sorting algorithms, and the JDK implementation uses an `O(nlogn)` algorithm.

The other parts of that method - `Arrays.copyOf(data,n)` and the loop, take `O(n)` time, since they iterate over the array one time.

Hence the overall running time is `O(nlogn)`.

Comment: Thank you, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm includes two main parts:

1. Sorting the array using standard `Arrays.sort` for `int[]` array.

Under the hood, it uses a Dual-Pivot Quicksort algorithm with average `O(n log n)` time complexity.

2. `for` loop to find any duplicate value in the sorted array with `O(n)` complexity which is "absorbed" by the greater complexity of sorting.

Thus, the resulting complexity is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It becomes much clearer